# Use the result of an XQuery value() query in another XQuery value() query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, xquery, sql-server-2014, xquery-sql

I'm trying to query the SSRS .rdl files which are in xml format. Here is an example of the relevant parts of the xml:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <DataSourceReference>DataSourceReference1</DataSourceReference>
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource2">
      <DataSourceReference>DataSourceReference2</DataSourceReference>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT a from b</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource2</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT c from d</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
...
```

And here is my SQL query so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#catalogtemp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #catalogtemp 
GO

SELECT Path, CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content)) XmlColumn
INTO #catalogtemp
FROM Catalog WHERE Type=2;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' as rdl10)

SELECT Path as ReportPath,
T1.dataset.value('./@Name','nvarchar(max)') DatasetName,
T1.dataset.value('(.//rdl10:CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as DatasetQuery,
T1.dataset.value('(.//rdl10:DataSourceName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as DataSourceName
FROM #catalogtemp
CROSS APPLY xmlColumn.nodes('//rdl10:DataSet') T1(dataset)
```

For the example xml above this would return:

```
ReportPath        DatasetName   DatasetQuery      DataSourceName
/path/to/report   DataSet1      SELECT a from b   DataSource1
/path/to/report   DataSet2      SELECT c from d   DataSource2
```

What I would like to do is add another column that looks up the `DataSourceReference` value for the `DataSource` node whose `Name` attribute matches the `DataSourceName` value of the `DataSet`. So the result of the query would look like this:

```
ReportPath        DatasetName   DatasetQuery      DataSourceName   DataSourceReference
/path/to/report   DataSet1      SELECT a from b   DataSource1      DataSourceReference1
/path/to/report   DataSet2      SELECT c from d   DataSource2      DataSourceReference2
```

I know that the following XQuery will return the `DataSourceReference` value for the `DataSource` node whose `Name` attribute is 'DataSource1':

```
T1.dataset.value('(../..//rdl10:DataSource[@Name="DataSource1"]//rdl10:DataSourceReference)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

but how do I write the query to look up the correct `DataSourceName` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO since `<DataSources>` are not included inside `<DataSets>` tags and viceversa, you need a subquery:

> ```
> ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' as rdl10)
>
> SELECT ct.Path as ReportPath,
>        T1.dataset.value('./@Name','nvarchar(max)') DatasetName,
>        T1.dataset.value('(.//rdl10:CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as DatasetQuery,
>        T1.dataset.value('(.//rdl10:DataSourceName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as DataSourceName
>        ,t.DSR
> FROM catalogtemp ct
> CROSS APPLY xmlColumn.nodes('//rdl10:DataSet') T1(dataset)
> JOIN (SELECT Path,
>              T2.dsrc.value('(./@Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as DSName,
>              T2.dsrc.value('(.//rdl10:DataSourceReference)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as DSR
>       FROM   catalogtemp
>       CROSS APPLY xmlColumn.nodes('//rdl10:DataSource') T2(dsrc)) t
> ON    t.Path = ct.Path
> AND   t.DSName = T1.dataset.value('(.//rdl10:DataSourceName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
> WHERE ct.Path = 'my report'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ReportPath | DatasetName | DatasetQuery    | DataSourceName | DSR                 
> :--------- | :---------- | :-------------- | :------------- | :-------------------
> my report  | DataSet1    | SELECT a from b | DataSource1    | DataSourceReference1
> my report  | DataSet2    | SELECT c from d | DataSource2    | DataSourceReference2
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd07df51bc600986b49710eaa889df94)*</kbd>

Comment: This works, thanks. One thing I needed to do to make this work with multiple reports is add a `Path` column in the subquery and join the subquery to catalogtemp on `Path` as well as `DSName`.

Comment: @jhnpckr This way? http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd07df51bc600986b49710eaa889df94